# HTML5 video jumps to end @ 40 secs

Tags: html5-video

I have a straightforward html5 video trial that jumps to end @ 40 secs.
It's pretty much cut and paste from W3C.
Acts the same way in Firefox and Chrome

Plays fine in vlc.
What in the world is going on.
I tried specifying codecs and could see no difference.

```
<style>
#mVideo
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    -moz-transform-origin: center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
}

</style>

<title>html5_rotate3</title>

</head>
<body>

<div><video controls="controls" width="320" height="240">
  <source src="http://www.meanroy.com/Music_Vids/BigSur_little_Girls.mp4">
   This is fallback text to display if the browser does not support the video element.
</video>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<video autobuffer="true" id="mVideo" controls="controls" width="320" height="240">
    <source src="http://www.meanroy.com/Music_Vids/BigSur_little_Girls.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    This is fallback text to display if the browser does not support the video element.
</video>

<div>
</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meanroy/v8w6a815/1/)

Comment: I believe the video must have something embedded which is causing this.

Comment: I found that the video was corrupted.